# Simple JQuery Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors

```
@foreach (var item in set)
 {
    <li>                               
    <div class="slidera_num">@item.VoteCount</div>
    <div class="slidera_button"><a href="#" id="vote" name="vote" onclick="vote(@item.Id);return false;">vote</a> </div>
    </li>
 }
```

I have this code that makes a list of images, and i want the user to click on Vote and want to make an ajax post and get JSON request and dispay in `div slidera_num`. Below is ajax call and it does return `{"vote":3}` .

```
function vote(idx) {

        $("#vote").click(function () {
            $.post("/Home/VoteAjax/", { id: idx}, function (result) {
                $(".slidera_num").html(result);
            });
        });
    };
```

However, everytime I click on vote, it increments the ajax calls, third time i click, it makes 5 calls or so. Another problem I have is since all the div will have class `.slidera_num` I dont want all of them to be updated same number.

how can i fix this?

thanks.

Comment: duplication of id `#vote` should avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the other answers have the duplicate covered.  To update the specific result only, instead of using *$(".slidera_num").html(result);*, use this:

```
$("#vote").click(function () {
    var thisLink = $(this);
    $.post("/Home/VoteAjax/", { id: idx}, function (result) {
        $(thisLink).closest("li").find(".slidera_num").html(result);
    });
});
```

*Edit* -- corrected.  Inside $.post, *this* does not refer to the click element, so you have to save a reference to it beforehand (*thisLink*).  From there, traverse to the parent *li*, then back down to the target ".slidera_num".

Comment: `item.closest(".slidera_num").html(response.vote); ` i have this code and not updating the div

Answer (score 2):

You are using a click event to bind a click event to the button.

Instead do this:

```
function vote(idx) {

        $.post("/Home/VoteAjax/", { id: idx}, function (result) {
            $(".slidera_num").html(result);
        });
};
```

You don't NEED to use jquery to bind the click event.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `onclick="vote(@item.Id);return false;"` from your html and just call your `vote()` function somewhere in javascript code.

Using onclick html attribute is old-school and no longer correct (although working).

Answer (score 2):

You  have duplicate id `#vote`, but ***ID Should be Unique*** and also remove `onClick`.

```
function vote(idx) {

        $('div.slidera_button a[name="vote"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var to = $(this);
            $.post("/Home/VoteAjax/", { id: idx}, function (result) {
                to.parent().prev('.slidera_button').html(result);
            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are specifying the ID of the a tag as "vote" in a loop. So all the elements coming from that loop will have the same ID. **ID's should be unique for elements**. So i would rewrite your code like this

```
@foreach (var item in set)
 {
    <li>                               
    <div class="slidera_num">@item.VoteCount</div>
    <div class="slidera_button"><a href="#" id="@item.Id" name="vote" >vote</a> </div>
    </li>
 }
```

And the script is

```
$(function(){
  $("div.slidera_button a").click(function(e){
  var item=$(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('@Url.Action("Vote","Ajax")', { id :item.attr("id") } ,function(response){
     item.closest(".slidera_num").html(response);
  });
});
```

Instead of hardcoding the path,  I am making use of `HTML helper method` to generate the path to that action method. So i dont need to worry about how many ../ to put in my URL.

Comment: thanks for the response, i m getting an exception complaning about URL.Action line. `{ id :item.attr("id") ` VS is complaining about that.